# How to add CSS to a specific div class - WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, shortcode

I am using a Wordpress theme named KALLYAS, and I am having trouble adding CSS to a specific class. This theme uses multiple shortcodes. So lets say I want to add a background with CSS to the gray area on the homepage only **WITHOUT EFFECTING THE GRAY AREA ON ANY OTHER PAGE**. also how would I go about adding CSS to a shortcode on a specific page aswell? I am guessing it is same way.

Comment: We aren't going to know what "the gray area" is on this specific theme.  You'll have to give us more detail.

Comment: cough, cough - AFFECTING. Have you tried using the `.home` class in your `CSS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That worked because if you notice on the code in the theme preview it says :

```
<body class="**home** page page-id-17 page-template-default res1170" data-twttr-rendered="true">
```

it would also work if you used any of them like :

```
.page-id-17 .greyarea { color:#ccc }

.home.page-id-17 .greyarea { color:#ccc }
```

Comment: Wow, thank you all so much for your responses. The .home in my CSS worked. Did this work because the word *home* in *.home* is the page name?

Answer (score 0):

You need to scope your CSS if you want it to just display on one page. Grab a unique class or ID from a parent on that page, and place that in front of your css selector.

Ex

```
.uniqueClass .greyarea { color:#ccc }
```